# Can't see my friend's likes, but another friend can

Tags: facebook, friends

My husband and I have the same Facebook friend.  When that friend likes a post, my husband sees the liked post but I do not.   Why is this? Can't I see the same friend's liked post?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the friends home page in facebook and click get notification available under friends drop down in cover page. further to this you will get future notification of your friends

Comment: I couldn’t understand your answer. Please I want to see the process by pictures.